# Stored procedure gives error while executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  usp_InsertUserDetails
    @FirstName nvarchar(20),
    @MiddleName nvarchar(20),
    @LastName nvarchar(30),
    @FullName nvarchar(50),
    @PhoneNo nvarchar(15),
    @FaxNo nvarchar(15),
    @EmployeeId nvarchar(64),
    @EmailAddress nvarchar(256),
    @SSOID nvarchar(76),
    @IsSFDC bit,
    @IsActive bit,
    @ManagerId int,
    @LastLoginDateTime datetime,
    @CreatedBy int,
    @CreatedDate datetime,
    @UpdatedBy int,
    @UpdatedDate datetime,
    @IsDeleted bit
AS   
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserDetail(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, FullName, PhoneNo, FaxNo, EmployeeId, EmailAddress, SSOID, IsSFDC, IsActive, ManagerId, LastLoginDateTime, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate, IsDeleted)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @FullName, @PhoneNo, @FaxNo, @EmployeeId, @EmailAddress, @SSOID, 0, 1, 2, GETDATE(), 1, GETDATE(), 1, GETDATE(), 0)
END
```

Executing like this :

```
exec usp_InsertUserDetails 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 0, 1, 1, GETDATE(), 1, GetDate(), 1, GETDATE(), 0
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this,

```
DECLARE @tmp DATETIME
SET @tmp = GETDATE()
exec usp_InsertUserDetails 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 0, 1, 1,@tmp , 1, @tmp, 1, @tmp, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a variable to store the current date/time:

```
declare @now datetime = getdate();

exec usp_InsertUserDetails 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
        'test', 'test', 'test', 0, 1, 1,
         @now, 1, @now, 1, @now, 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a stored procedure with a parameter that is a function call, getdate() in this case. Assign to a variable instead.